# How to write "knowledge to all" in classical latin?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

How to write "knowledge to all" in Classical Latin?

Google translate gave me "In omni scientia".
But I also had "Omnes enim scientiae" or "Omnis enim scientia" and a scholar gave me "Scientia per omnibus".

Which one corresponds the best? Or is there yet another wording which would be more accurate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Translate is very unreliable with Latin.
Let me go through the proposed translations:

- *In omni scientia* means "in all knowledge" or "there is knowledge in all". The translation depends on whether *scientia* is nominative or ablative — the two forms look alike for this word.
- *Omnes enim scientiae* means "but all knowledges".
- *Omnis enim scientia* is the same in singular: "but all knowledge".
- *Scientia per omnibus* is ungrammatical. With *per* you should have accusative but *omnibus* is in dative (or ablative). It is better not to use a preposition here.

It should be noted that *scientia* also means "science", but I think this meaning is not yet present in classical Latin.

The last suggestion is closest to a good one.
***Scientia omnibus*** means "knowledge to all".
In Latin "to all" is expressed with the single word *omnibus* (in dative) without any preposition.

Comment: *Pro patria* is **'On behalf of** one's Country.'  Perhaps the scholar was thinking of  *pro* + ablative., in this Centenary year.

Comment: @Hugh, perhaps they indeed meant *scientia pro omnibus* (knowledge on behalf of everyone). I suppose this could also be translated as "knowledge for all", but the meaning is quite far from the OP's intention if I understand it correctly.